# Problem in slideDown() functtion of Gquery

Tags: jquery, gwt, gquery

I want to show popupPanel when i click on slideDown button ,but at the start my popupPanel is hidden

using

```
       popupPanel.getElement().setAttribute("style", "display:none");
```

but when i click on slideDown button it slide down very fast

& my onClick code  is

```
 @Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent arg0) {

    if (arg0.getSource() == slideDown) {

            $(DOM.getElementById("popupPanel")).as(Effects).slideUp(Speed.SLOW);

     }

 }
```

Can u help me ?

Comment: Have you been able to make this work please? I'm using animate($$("top: '-=50'"), 1000, Easing.SWING) but that's not exactly what I want. :(

Comment: Ha, now looking about at this, and being more experience. I realize that there is no `public void` in JavaScript. Lol, this looks more like Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
$('#popupPanel').css('display','none');
$('#ID_to_be_clicked').click(function(){    
    $('#popupPanel').slideToogle(3000); 
});
```

Their is not `public` nor `void` keyword in JavaScript. I think this is another case of `JavaScript is Java`...which it isn't.